# Centering text on responsive site using Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to center the three words below, 'Dream', 'Breathe', 'Ride' on small screens. Have tried margin: 0 auto; and others, but haven't found anything that works.

Any ideas?

I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap 4.

Many thanks.

Here is the html:

```
<section id="home-section">
                <div class="container">
                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="text">
                            <h1 class="display-2 text1">Dream.</h1>
                             <h1 class="display-2 text2">Breathe.</h1>
                             <h1 class="display-2 text3">Ride.</h1>
                         </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      </section>
```

Comment: `text-align:center` doesn't work? Also you don't seem to be using any BS classes on the `.text` div.

Comment: Bootstrap class `text-center` or simply in css `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@media` query to make your code responsive to screen size, for example, the below code will make the content of class `text` aligned center on screens below `991px` width.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
 .text{
  text-align:center;
 }
}
```

```html
<section id="home-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="text">
        <h1 class="display-2 text1">Dream.</h1>
        <h1 class="display-2 text2">Breathe.</h1>
        <h1 class="display-2 text3">Ride.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks all for your help. My problem however, remains :~

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of what you want exactly ?